# ASP.Net MVC Application URL Schema

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I have inherited an existing ASP.Net MVC C# web application solution.

Currently, there are two separate Web Application projects.

1. An Admin site - used to managed the content of the public facing site.
2. The public facing site

Currently, the public facing site is not in production; only the Admin site is deployed on Windows Server 2012 running IIS 8.0 using the client's domain e.g. www.mysite.com

The client would like the public facing site and the admin site to be accessibile via the same domain:

Public: www.mysite.com
Admin: www.mysite.com/admin or admin.mysite.com

Is there any way to achieve this given the two sets of functionality are currently encapsulated in different Web Applications?

I'm wondering if:

1. Is there a way to achieve the above with sub-domains or some other feature of IIS
2. Or if its best to move all the Admin functionality into an MVC Area within a single Web Application

Discussions on the pros/cons of each approach (or links to resources) would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather move admin site and public facing site in single web app in separate area as OP said.

You can use host-header facility in IIS to adjust root domain url to admin.mysite.com (or such).

advantage of such approach is maintenance will be easier as code base is part of single vsnet solution, Assuming public facing site will have lot more content/controller/views and admin site will have less of those, there is no point in maintaining separate .SLN for admin.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I was never considering a separate Solution for both web apps - they would be separate web apps but under a single Solution file - in which case the benefit of easier code maintenance is mute I believe.